# how to create calculated field in mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql, calculated-columns

i have a table like below:

```
create table info (username varchar(30),otherinfo varchar(100));
```

now i want to alter this table to have new field and this field has to have default value as

```
md5(username)
```

something like below:

```
alter table info add NewField varchar(100) default md5(username);
```

how to do so?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Per MySQL [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) (emphasis added) you cannot have an expression in a default value:

> 10.1.4. Data Type Default Values
>
> The DEFAULT value clause in a data
>   type specification indicates a default
>   value for a column. With one
>   exception, **the default value must be a
>   constant; it cannot be a function or
>   an expression**. This means, for
>   example, that you cannot set the
>   default for a date column to be the
>   value of a function such as NOW() or
>   CURRENT_DATE. The exception is that
>   you can specify CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as
>   the default for a TIMESTAMP column.

I've tested that the following trigger works for your intent:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTriggerName
  BEFORE INSERT ON info
  FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.NewField = md5(NEW.username);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should write a Trigger to achieve this functionality, given that MySQL has a md5 function built in or you are capable to either write or find a md5 algorithm for MySQL :)

Take a look @ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

for the md5 function take a look here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/encryption-functions.html

Also, you should know that MD5 is not a [secure algorithm anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768248/is-md5-really-that-bad).