# the default value must be a constant; why?

Tags: mysql, sql, default-constraint

[in this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html) said

> the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an
>   expression

can you tell me why ? why we must give constant default value?

Comment: Because sometimes it'd be helpful it if wasn't; I'd sometimes quite like the default `time` to be `now()` for example. Knowing *why* sometimes makes an irritation easier to deal with...

Comment: Actually this is not specific to SQL. Almost all programming languages are created the way that only constants can be used as default values for variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation in MySQL.
You can either use another RDBMS or get around the problem [using a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236912/how-to-create-calculated-field-in-mysql/4237064#4237064).

```
CREATE TRIGGER yourtable_insert BEFORE INSERT ON `yourtable`
    FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.youraddedcolumn = NOW(), NEW.yourupdatedcolumn = NOW();
```

Answer (score 1):

One reason I can think of is ambiguity. Should the expression be evaluated before storing it as a default or for each INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

Note that there's one non-constant value you can use in a table definition:

```
stamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This can only be used on a `TIMESTAMP` column, but it's useful enough.