# MySQL fill value into a field by rule

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db with a table with 3 columns "id, fullname, picpath".
After a new value is set into the table from a php file, is it possible to fill the "picpath" with the value of 'md5( new id that is created )" by setting this in the properties of the field itself using "MySQL Workbench" or an SQL query?

Comment: Duplicate? "how to create calculated field in mysql?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236912/how-to-create-calculated-field-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks I was not sure what to look for exactly